# Margin-left animate to the end of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one wrapper div (the grey background) and 5 squares inside it. After the press of a button, the blue one moves and has to stop at the end of the wrapper div, but it goes behind it. How do I make it go to the end of the div, and not behind it?

There is what I've tried so far:

```
<button id = "start">
Start
</button>

<div style="background-color:rgb(201, 201, 201);width:80%;height:250px" id="horsewrapper">
        <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: blue;" id="horse1">1</div>
        <div style="background-color:red;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse2">1</div>
        <div style="background-color:green;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse3">1</div>
        <div style="background-color:yellow;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse4">1</div>
        <div style="background-color:orange;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse5">1</div>
    </div>
```

Demo can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/wqrun6ny/2/

Thanks

Comment: You have to animate blue div to (100% - blue div's width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/wqrun6ny/3/
```

Margin 100% adds margin to widh of element. To avoid this you should add to your animate function left property which is equal to width of element:

```
$('#horse1').animate({"margin-left":"100%", 'left': -100} ....
```

but it will works only if element has position:relative

Answer (score 1):

You can make a calculation before start the animation. It takes the width of the wrapper and substract it the width of the "horse":

https://jsfiddle.net/wqrun6ny/4/

```
$('#start').click(function(){
  var margin = $('#horsewrapper').width() - $('#horse1').width();
  $('#horse1').animate({"margin-left": margin},{"duration":1000,"easing":"linear"});
});
```

### Edit

According with the request in comments, you can use `stop()`method and then reinitialise the animation, it works perfectly:

https://jsfiddle.net/wqrun6ny/15/

```
$('#start').click(function(){
  animate($('#horse1'));
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $('#horse1').stop();
  animate($('#horse1'));
});

var animate = function(element) {
  var margin = $('#horsewrapper').width() - element.width();
  element.animate({"margin-left": margin},{"duration":5000,"easing":"linear"});
};
```

You will notice a problem, if you don't push the button but you resize the window, it will start the animation. To avoid this you can add a flag or check if the div is in the initial position.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, but if I resize the window when the blue box is in motion, it goes far behind the wrapper. Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate margin first, then animate according to margin.
Try like this:

```
$('#start').click(function(){
var mar = $('#horsewrapper').width() - $('#horse1').width();
$('#horse1').animate({"margin-left": mar},  {"duration":1000,"easing":"linear"});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/wqrun6ny/14/

You could calculate the width of the container, and subtract the width of the boxes your moving. Pushing it 100% will result in what your demo is displaying.

If its a static box width the same width, you can just use a static pixel value as well.

```
var horsewrapperWidth = $('#horsewrapper').width() -100;
```

100 is the width of your "horses".

```
$('#horse1').animate({"margin-left": horsewrapperWidth + 'px'},{"duration":5000,"easing":"linear"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way !

```js
$('#start').click(function() {
// added this variable to get width of box
  var box = $('#horsewrapper').width();

  $('#horse1').finish().css("margin-left", "initial");
  $('#horse1').animate({
    "margin-left": box - 100 // box - width of horse (100%-100px)
  }, {
    "duration": 5000,
    "easing": "linear"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">
  Start
</button>

<div style="background-color:rgb(201, 201, 201);width:80%;height:250px" id="horsewrapper">
  <div style="height: 50px; width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: blue;" id="horse1">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:red;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse2">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:green;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse3">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse4">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:orange;text-align:center;height:50px;width:100px" id="horse5">1</div>
</div>
```